# System Dictionary implementation explanation?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hash

I'm trying to understand how the internals of C#'s generic Dictionary work. I decompiled and got the dictionary code. I re-wrote it slightly separating the keys/values/hashcodes to separate arrays (I omitted the enumerator and interface implementations because they're irrelevant)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    int[] _Buckets;
    int[] _HashCodes;
    int[] _Next;
    int _Count;
    int _FreeList;
    int _FreeCount;
    TKey[] _Keys;
    TValue[] _Values;

    readonly IEqualityComparer<TKey> _Comparer;

    public int Count {
        get { return _Count - _FreeCount; }
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key] {
        get {
            int index = FindIndex(key);
            if (index >= 0)
                return _Values[index];
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(key.ToString());
        }
        set { Insert(key, value, false); }
    }

    public Dictionary() : this(0, null) {
    }

    public Dictionary(int capacity) : this(capacity, null) {
    }

    public Dictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) : this(0, comparer) {
    }

    public Dictionary(int capacity, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) {
        if (capacity < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("capacity");
        Initialize(capacity);
        _Comparer = (comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public Dictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary) : this(dictionary, null)
    {
    }

    public Dictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        : this((dictionary != null) ? dictionary.Count : 0, comparer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> current in dictionary)
            Add(current.Key, current.Value);
    }

    public bool ContainsValue(TValue value) {
        if (value == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < _Count; i++) {
                if (_HashCodes[i] >= 0 && _Values[i] == null)
                    return true;
            }
        } else {
            var defaultComparer = EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
            for (int i = 0; i < _Count; i++) {
                if (_HashCodes[i] >= 0 && defaultComparer.Equals(_Values[i], value))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key) {
        return FindIndex(key) >= 0;
    }

    public void Clear() {
        if (_Count <= 0)
            return;

        for (int i = 0; i < _Buckets.Length; i++)
            _Buckets[i] = -1;

        Array.Clear(_Keys, 0, _Count);
        Array.Clear(_Values, 0, _Count);
        Array.Clear(_HashCodes, 0, _Count);
        Array.Clear(_Next, 0, _Count);

        _FreeList = -1;
        _Count = 0;
        _FreeCount = 0;
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value) {
        Insert(key, value, true);
    }

    private void Resize(int newSize, bool forceNewHashCodes) {
        int[] bucketsCopy = new int[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < bucketsCopy.Length; i++)
            bucketsCopy[i] = -1;

        var keysCopy = new TKey[newSize];
        var valuesCopy = new TValue[newSize];
        var hashCodesCopy = new int[newSize];
        var nextCopy = new int[newSize];

        Array.Copy(_Values, 0, valuesCopy, 0, _Count);
        Array.Copy(_Keys, 0, keysCopy, 0, _Count);
        Array.Copy(_HashCodes, 0, hashCodesCopy, 0, _Count);
        Array.Copy(_Next, 0, nextCopy, 0, _Count);

        if (forceNewHashCodes) {
            for (int i = 0; i < _Count; i++) {
                if (hashCodesCopy[i] != -1)
                    hashCodesCopy[i] = (_Comparer.GetHashCode(keysCopy[i]) & 2147483647);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _Count; i++) {
            int index = hashCodesCopy[i] % newSize;
            nextCopy[i] = bucketsCopy[index];
            bucketsCopy[index] = i;
        }
        _Buckets = bucketsCopy;
        _Keys = keysCopy;
        _Values = valuesCopy;
        _HashCodes = hashCodesCopy;
        _Next = nextCopy;
    }

    private void Resize()
    {
        Resize(PrimeHelper.ExpandPrime(_Count), false);
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        int hash = _Comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 2147483647;
        int index = hash % _Buckets.Length;
        int num = -1;
        for (int i = _Buckets[index]; i >= 0; i = _Next[i]) {
            if (_HashCodes[i] == hash && _Comparer.Equals(_Keys[i], key)) {
                if (num < 0)
                    _Buckets[index] = _Next[i];
                else
                    _Next[num] = _Next[i];

                _HashCodes[i] = -1;
                _Next[i] = _FreeList;
                _Keys[i] = default(TKey);
                _Values[i] = default(TValue);
                _FreeList = i;
                _FreeCount++;
                return true;
            }
            num = i;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void Insert(TKey key, TValue value, bool add) {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
        if (_Buckets == null)
            Initialize(0);
        int hash = _Comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 2147483647;
        int index = hash % _Buckets.Length;
        for (int i = _Buckets[index]; i >= 0; i = _Next[i]) {
            if (_HashCodes[i] == hash && _Comparer.Equals(_Keys[i], key)) {
                if (add)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Key already exists: " + key);
                _Values[i] = value;
                return;
            }
        }
        int num;
        if (_FreeCount > 0) {
            num = _FreeList;
            _FreeList = _Next[num];
            _FreeCount--;
        } else {
            if (_Count == _Keys.Length) {
                Resize();
                index = hash % _Buckets.Length;
            }
            num = _Count;
            _Count++;
        }
        _HashCodes[num] = hash;
        _Next[num] = _Buckets[index];
        _Keys[num] = key;
        _Values[num] = value;
        _Buckets[index] = num;
    }

    private void Initialize(int capacity) {
        int prime = PrimeHelper.GetPrime(capacity);
        _Buckets = new int[prime];
        for (int i = 0; i < _Buckets.Length; i++)
            _Buckets[i] = -1;

        _Keys = new TKey[prime];
        _Values = new TValue[prime];
        _HashCodes = new int[prime];
        _Next = new int[prime];

        _FreeList = -1;
    }

    private int FindIndex(TKey key) {
        if (key == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        if (_Buckets != null) {
            int hash = _Comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 2147483647;
            for (int i = _Buckets[hash % _Buckets.Length]; i >= 0; i = _Next[i]) {
                if (_HashCodes[i] == hash && _Comparer.Equals(_Keys[i], key))
                    return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value) {
        int index = FindIndex(key);
        if (index >= 0) {
            value = _Values[index];
            return true;
        }
        value = default(TValue);
        return false;
    }

    public TValue ValueOrDefault(TKey key) {
        return ValueOrDefault(key, default(TValue));
    }

    public TValue ValueOrDefault(TKey key, TValue defaultValue) {
        //return this[key, defaultValue];
        int index = FindIndex(key);
        if (index >= 0)
            return _Values[index];
        return defaultValue;
    }

    private static class PrimeHelper {

        public static readonly int[] Primes = new int[] {
            3, 7, 11, 17,
            23, 29, 37, 47,
            59, 71, 89, 107,
            131, 163, 197, 239,
            293, 353, 431, 521,
            631, 761, 919, 1103,
            1327, 1597, 1931, 2333,
            2801, 3371, 4049, 4861,
            5839, 7013, 8419, 10103,
            12143, 14591, 17519, 21023,
            25229, 30293, 36353, 43627,
            52361, 62851, 75431, 90523,
            108631, 130363, 156437, 187751,
            225307, 270371, 324449, 389357,
            467237, 560689, 672827, 807403,
            968897, 1162687, 1395263, 1674319,
            2009191, 2411033, 2893249, 3471899,
            4166287, 4999559, 5999471, 7199369
        };

        public static bool IsPrime(int candidate) {
            if ((candidate & 1) != 0) {
                int num = (int)Math.Sqrt((double)candidate);
                for (int i = 3; i <= num; i += 2) {
                    if (candidate % i == 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            return candidate == 2;
        }

        public static int GetPrime(int min) {
            if (min < 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("min < 0");

            for (int i = 0; i < PrimeHelper.Primes.Length; i++) {
                int prime = PrimeHelper.Primes[i];
                if (prime >= min)
                    return prime;
            }
            for (int i = min | 1; i < 2147483647; i += 2) {
                if (PrimeHelper.IsPrime(i) && (i - 1) % 101 != 0)
                    return i;
            }
            return min;
        }

        public static int ExpandPrime(int oldSize) {
            int num = 2 * oldSize;
            if (num > 2146435069 && 2146435069 > oldSize) {
                return 2146435069;
            }
            return PrimeHelper.GetPrime(num);
        }
    }
}
```

What's confusing me is:

- The `_FreeList` and `_FreeCount` variables: what do they represent?
- What's the difference between `Count` and `_Count`?
- So `_Next` seems to be related to hash collision, does it store the next index of the key/value that has the same hash?
- What's `num` doing in `Remove`?
- So given a `Key` we compute `Index = GetHashCode(Key) % Buckets.Length;` which gives us an index that we could use in the `_Keys/_Values/_HashCodes` arrays. Why do we need to compare `_HashCodes[i] == hash`? I mean we got the index by computing the hash, so of course `_Keys[i]` hash the same hash right?

Note that there was an actual use case for decompiling the code and using it. Unity3D doesn't know how to serialize dictionaries and the ways you get around it normally is not so great, so I took the actual code of Dictionary and annotated the necessary fields with `[SerializeField]`, now Unity can serialize the class without any wrappers.

Comment: As a small side note, the actual source code is available from Microsoft, you don't have to decompile it. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs

Comment: I know but I wanted a version that took the less amount of modifications to get it working in an external environment. I looked at the source from MS but they had a lot of internal calls that required reflection to be used externally.

Comment: I think it's worst code you could analyze, see https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs,
see MONO implementation
https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs
both are readable and understandable

Comment: Also not knowing 100% what you are trying to achieve, wouldn't it make more sense to derive a subclass from `Dictionary`, say `SerializableDictionary` that implements the serialization behavior you desire rather than starting from scratch?

Comment: @ФагимСадыков actually the first link is the same implementation you see in this post.

Comment: @amg-argh No that wouldn't work because you *must* mark the keys/values data in the actual dictionary class with [SerializeField] - yes you can write wrappers but like I said they're a headache and contain lots of caveats in Unity.

Comment: Of course it is but not same - in question we see decompiled code

Comment: @vexe I imagine there would be a way, say exposing a new property and having that serialize / deserialize. You will have caveats no matter what way you go, for example a method that takes a (core) Dictionary as it's parameter, won't take your implementation, but it would take a subclass. Nonetheless good luck with your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation that you show uses arrays `_Keys` to store keys and `_Values` to store their corresponding values. Only the portion of these arrays from index zero, inclusive, to index `_Count`, exclusive, is occupied. The elements at `_Count` and above are not used.

`_Keys` and `_Values` arrays are populated sequentially on addition. When a removal occurs, the corresponding elements are placed on *free list*. When the next addition occurs, the last element returned to free list is used before considering the expansion to the element at `_Count`.

> `_Next` seems to be related to hash collision, does it store the next index of the key/value that has the same hash?

`_Next` has two purposes, depending on whether the corresponding item is used or is on a free list.

- When the item `i`is used, `_Next[i]` represents the index of the next element with *colliding* hash code (it is not necessarily the same hash code!)
- When the item `i` is on a free list, `_Next[i]` represents the next item on the free list (i.e. the item that was placed on free list before `i`-th, if any).

> What's the difference between `Count` and `_Count`?

`_Count` is the high watermark of the `_Keys` and `_Values` arrays; `Count` is the actual count, which is computed as high watermark less the number of items placed on the free list (i.e. max added minus currently removed).

> So given a Key we compute `Index = GetHashCode(Key) % Buckets.Length;` which gives us an index that we could use in the `_Keys`/`_Values`/`_HashCodes` arrays. Why do we need to compare `_HashCodes[i] == hash`?

Because `GetHashCode(Key) % Buckets.Length` remainder may be the same for different values of hash code. You can optimize the code by comparing hash code before invoking `Equals`, although this step is not necessary.

> What's `num` doing in `Remove`?

An item that we are removing may be part of a list of items with colliding hash codes. The item may be at the head of the list, or it may be somewhere else on the list. The code uses `num` to treat these situations differently:

- When the item is at the head of its list, the next item needs to be "promoted" to the head by adjusting `_Buckets[]`
- When the item is not at the head of the list, its `_Next[]` index needs to be adjusted without promoting to the head.

`next` starts at a negative number, and switches to a non-negative number after the initial iteration. The check `if (num < 0)` means "are we on the first iteration?"

Comment: Regarding hashcode compare, if there are several items in the list of entries that map to the same bucket, initially comparing hashcodes, and only then comparing keys can be much faster than comparing keys for each item in the list. I don't think they have to compare hashcodes, I think it's an optimization.

Comment: Great answer! Just to make sure I also understand `_Buckets`: If I iterate over each value in it and use it as an index in the `_Keys` and `_Values` arrays, I would be basically iterating over the keys/values of the dictionary correct?

Comment: @vexe Not exactly: when `_Buckets[i]` is non-negative, `_Keys[_Buckets[i]]` contains the first key in the chain of items with colliding hash codes. When there are collisions, iterating over `_Buckets` with non-negative values would yield fewer key/value pairs than there are in the dictionary. If you want to get all keys/values in bucket order, you need to follow the chain of `_Next`s for each bucket that has one.'

Comment: If there was 5 pairs in the dictionary, it means that there's 5 keys, and 5 values, but it doesn't necessarily mean there's 5 elements in `_Buckets` unless there's no collision right? if there is collision then the sum of the elements used in `_Buckets` plus the ones used in `_Next` should be equal to 5 correct?

Comment: @vexe You are right on the first point. On the second point, there is a tiny correction: it's the number of elements used in `_Buckets` plus the ones used in `_Next` minus `_FreeCount`, because some of the `_Next`s may be on free list.

Comment: Thank you! My source of confusion is `_FreeList` - why is it called a 'list' (can store multiple values) if it's just an integer? (can store one value) - and I'm assuming that `_FreeCount` is the count of said list? if you could elaborate a bit more on that it would be great!

Comment: @vexe I agree, `_FreeList` is not the best name for the variable. I think `_FreeListHead` would have been a better name for it. This is the index of the first`_Key`/`_Value` pair on the free list. The rest of the list can be traversed by following the corresponding `_Next` indexes.